# Transactions not working in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions, sql-update, rollback

I have a Person model which has attributes **name** and **address**.I am doing this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
Person.where(:id=>[1]).update_all(:address => "Newyork") #1st update  
Person.where(:id=>[2]).update_all(:address1 => "Newyork") #2nd update  
end
```

I intentionally put `address1` here which is not the property/attribute of model Person. As `address1` is not the property of this model so 2nd `update` should get failed and 1st `update` should get rollbacked too.

But in my case, 2nd `update` is getting failed but 1st `update` is not rolling back.Why?

Comment: What database are you using? E.g. MySql with MyISAM storage engine doesn't support transactions.

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: @koffeinfrei : I am using mysql.     
@liuzxc : I am getting error message:      

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'persons.address1' in 'field list': UPDATE `persons` SET `persons`.`address1` = 'Newyork' WHERE `persons`.`id` in (2)

Comment: Can you check what storage engine you are using (`SELECT ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'`)?

Comment: @koffeinfrei : It's InnoDB. I checked the same on my friends machine and same is happening. Can you please check this simple example at your end and figure out what the issue is?

Comment: I'm currently on the way... Can you try to reproduce the behaviour with a different database, e.g. postgres?